# java enum << operator

Tags: java, enums

What kind of values are we expecting for a enum class like one below. Confused about << operators

```
public enum FrequencyEnum {

    DAILY       (1), 
    WEEKLY      (1 << 1), 
    BI_WEEKLY   (1 << 2), 
    MONTHLY     (1 << 3), 


    private short id;


    private FrequencyEnum(int id) {
        this.id = (short) id;
    }

    public short getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static FrequencyEnum valueOf(short id) {
        for (FrequencyEnum status : FrequencyEnum.values()) {
            if (status.getId() == id) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: See the Java tutorial [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Comment: What are you even asking?

Comment: if you check tutorial in above comment you would see how your enums initialized : DAILY (1), 
    WEEKLY      (2), 
    BI_WEEKLY   (4), 
    MONTHLY     (8),

Answer (score 0):

The `<<`is the left-shift operator. In this context, you are passing various integer values to the enum constructor (as kiruwka mentioned).

See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html